# Как исправить ошибку при запуске скрипта с помощью PM2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, windows-server-2012, coffeescript

я использую скрипт написанный на **coffee** и он нормально запускается командой `coffee название.coffee`,
но при попытке запустить его с помощью **pm2** у меня выскакивает ошибка:

> [PM2] [ERROR] Interpreter /coffee does not seems to be available

*Он там ещё в середине пишет путь до модуля coffee в своей папке.*

Сам пакет **coffee** установлен, пробовал команду `pm2 install cooffeescript` не помогла, запускаю на Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (*На Ubuntu такая же проблема*).

Вот скрин проблемы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине есть путь. Что лежит по этому пути?

Comment: Вот вам http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1475066027/d957f335/14296584.png

Comment: Ну вот и ответ - кофескрипт туды не установлен

Comment: А собственно, как мне туда его поставить?
Просто скачать пакет и засунуть туда?